# view webp images with wordpress htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need a little help on Wordpress. I am creating a custom theme. Now I would like to add to the classic wordpress htaccess file a rule that allows you to check if the browser supports webp images and if in the directory there is a webp file with the same name as the jpeg file, show the webp file. I have already tried several solutions found on the web, but have not been able to solve the problem yet. Could anyone help me?

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (.*)(\.(jpe?g|png))$
    
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp -f
    
    RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
  </IfModule>
  
  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType image/webp .webp
  </IfModule>
```

this is what i feel. I have inserted the code both above and below the wordpress code, but the result does not change.

This is my current htaccess

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} image/webp
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  (.*)(\.(jpe?g|png))$
      RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
      AddType image/webp .webp
    </IfModule>
    
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # Le direttive (linee) tra `BEGIN WordPress` e `END WordPress` sono
    # generate dinamicamente, e dovrebbero essere modificate solo tramite i filtri di WordPress.
    # Ogni modifica alle direttive tra questi marcatori verrà sovrascritta.
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What happens exactly? The code you've posted looks like it should work (if placed _above_ the WP front-controller), although it could be tidied a bit (eg. the 2nd `RewriteCond` directive is entirely superfluous). Are you sure you are not seeing a cached response? What other directives do you have? (Where is the `accept` env var being set?)

Comment: The htaccess file is the classic wordpress one, I didn't add anything else. I entered the code posted above. Then I uploaded two files with the same name, one .jpg and the other .webp, but unfortunately I always see the jpeg file.

Comment: Try (temporarily) removing the 3 `RewriteCond` directives.

Comment: I modified the htaccess file, but now I don't see any images anymore.

Comment: ...and you request just that one `.jpg` file? (ie. don't request the webpage itself - that won't work)

Comment: Nothing to do, it is not displayed, below I have reported my current htaccess

Comment: You need to test this without WordPress... so remove everything except for the `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ $1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,L]` directives. What is the image URL you are requesting? Where is the `.htaccess` file located? It would seem WordPress is installed in a `/wordpress` subdirectory. Is `/wordpress` present in the URL?